# Run command at GUI startup

Tags: x11, login

I would like to add a command and an application at startup without installing anything. This is the command I want to run at startup:

```
xset m 2/1 4
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this, check this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autostarting

Comment: @Aventinus I added the command I show in the post in xinitrc, it works but until I login in my archlinux account after boot. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Jakla `.xinitrc` is the right place if you use `startx`. If you log in in graphical mode then it depends on your session type. How do you log in? If applicable, what session type do you select? What window manager or desktop environment do you use?